# how to splice two tensors in tenforflow

Tags: tensorflow

Suppose i've read in a tensor of filenames `imgfiles_op` and their corresponding labels `labels_op`, I could see prints with a batch_size of filenames followed by a batch_size of labels with the following snippets:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

    for i in range(2):
        print ("Batch= ", i)
        pair = tf.convert_to_tensor([imgfiles_op, labels_op]).eval()

        print ('imgfile=%s, label=%s' % (pair[0],
                                         pair[1]))

    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

My question is how can I get prints like this format: `"<filename> <label>"`.
I didn't get the following work, and running this simply hangs. My idea is to make a list of such pairs. So '`pair_list`' below should be of size batch_size.

```
for i in range(2):
        print ("Batch= ", i)
        pair_list_op = tf.train.slice_input_producer([imgfiles_op, labels_op],
                                                     shuffle=False)
        pair_list = sess.run(pair_list_op)
        for p in pair_list:
            print ('imgfile=%s, label=%s' % (p[0],
                                             p[1]))
```

Questions:
1. Why the second code snippet hangs? Is there a good way to ensure any TF code won't hang? This effect is frustrating to new TF users.

2. Certainly I could do this python way, but I wonder what's the TF way to do so.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution might be this:

```
p1 = tf.constant(['f1','f2','f3'])
p2 = tf.constant(['1','0','1'])
p3 = tf.stack([p1, p2])
p4 = tf.stack([p1, p2],axis=1)
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(p3))
print(sess.run(p4))
```

Output :

```
array([['f1', 'f2', 'f3'],
       ['1', '0', '1']], dtype=object)

array([['f1', '1'],
       ['f2', '0'],
       ['f3', '1']], dtype=object)
```

In the second case (p4), you can see filenames and labels can appear as you specified. You can stack image_filenames and labels with axis = 1.

Does this helps you ??

Comment: Thanks! tf.stack() helps! But I'd like to know more why slice_input_producer() doesn't work and especially why the program hangs.

Comment: @galactica, I am not sure why you put graph in a for loop. slice_input_producer is a graph node. for loop should be before sess.run line. If you run the sess.run(pair_list_op) - it should produce the result. But again, you will be doing in python way in the end. tf.stack() is a better option for you I guess.